# Cocoapods clipper install error with WhirlyGlobe

Tags: ios, svn, cocoapods, clipperlib

I am trying to install WhirlyGlobe in my project using cocoapods but I am getting "Error installing clipper". I have added the below lines in podfile.

```
platform :ios, '8.1'

pod 'WhirlyGlobe'
pod 'WhirlyGlobeResources'
```

I am getting below error when executing command `pod install`

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.5.4)
Installing FMDB (2.5)
Installing GoogleProtobuf (2.6.1)
Installing KissXML (5.0)
Installing SMCalloutView (2.1.2)
Installing WhirlyGlobe (2.3)
Installing WhirlyGlobeResources (2.3)
Installing boost (1.51.0a)
Installing clipper (5.1.4)

[!] Error installing clipper
[!] /usr/local/bin/svn export --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --force http://svn.code.sf.net/p/polyclipping/code/tags/5.1.4 /var/folders/0n/6t4k5zhd2nnf05zjtw2hj4nm0000gp/T/d20150525-13490-1ivesgq
```

Answer (score 1):

Clipper installed cleanly for me in a brand new project using the example Podfile on the WG-Maply page.

I did run into another version problem with the Podspec, though.  While I fix that, I suggest using the binary version or installing from the github repo.

Comment: Binary version is working fine but I want to use the cocoa pods in project. So whenever the issue gets resolve then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have Xcode 9.2.
I have CocoaPods 1.4.0.
I have svn 1.9.4.
I have hg 4.5.2. (installed from `brew install mercurial`)

1. I create a new Objective-C project (name "Lovelace"), and I set Deployment target at iOS 8.1
2. I create a new Podfile with:

   ```
   target 'Lovelace'
   platform :ios, '8.1'
   pod 'WhirlyGlobe'
   pod 'WhirlyGlobeResources'
   ```
3. I run `pod install`:

   > Analyzing dependencies
   >   Downloading dependencies
   >   Installing AFNetworking (2.4.1)
   >   Installing FMDB (2.7.2)
   >   Installing SMCalloutView (2.1.5)
   >   Installing WhirlyGlobe (2.4)
   >   Installing WhirlyGlobeResources (2.3)
   >   Installing boost (1.51.0)
   >   Installing clipper (6.1.3a)
   >   Installing eigen (3.2.10)
   >   Installing libjson (7.6.1)
   >   Installing proj4 (4.8.0)
   >   Installing tinyxml (2.1.0)
   >   Generating Pods project
   >   Integrating client project

So it's not possible to reproduce your issue anymore. It may have been solved with newer versions of the pods, or newer version of CocoaPods, or newer version of svn. Or the svn access to http://svn.code.sf.net/ is now fixed.

Note that WhirlyGlobe made a tutorial for CocoaPods installation: https://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/tutorial/ios/building_from_cocoapod.html